# How to get stderr after error redirection in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that runs some tasks and along the way redirects error to /stderr.

Which means the script starts with:

```
exec 2>$TMPDIR/stderr
```

Now, the only thing I want it, after the script finished running, how do I get back any potential error that has been written to stderr? Because, I would like to show errors only after bash is finished running all the script.

Comment: `cat "$TMPDIR"/stderr` at the end?

Comment: @j.a. you are right, but I would like to echo it as an error. cat would just list it as item list. Is there a way around this?

Comment: If you would like to output during execution **and** write to `"$TMPDIR"/stderr`, you will need to redirect both `stdout/stderr` to `tee`. Or if you truly want it after: `exec 2>$TMPDIR/stderr; cat "$TMPDIR"/stderr` as one command (or one after the other)

Comment: Never heard of `tee` before. Can you add more details please?

Comment: There are a some things that can be helpful for you. One is already mentioned `tee`, another one is `trap` (shell builtin) which you can use to run some code when you script ends its life automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print the content of `$TMPDIR/stderr` at the end with:

```
cat "$TMPDIR"/stderr
```

To print that "as an error" (as you said in a comment), you're probably looking for this:

```
cat "$TMPDIR"/stderr >&2
```

That is, redirect the output of the `cat` command to `stderr`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but too noob to think of. But one more thing thought, since I want to say at the end `"Script failed because of error ..."` I would like to know if there was actually an error at the end, or not. How do I check if there is an error in `$TMPDIR/stderr` first? Is there like a function to check if that file is empty or not?

Comment: You can use `if [ -s "$TMPDIR"/stderr ]; then` to do something only if the file is not empty (= there were errors)

Answer (score 0):

If you direct all stderr messages to `/dev/stderr` or`&2` (destination file for storing error messages), these messages will not be stored in a file. It is understood in bash that "/dev/stderr" is the screen/terminal.

Therefore you can direct all stderr messages to an stderr message file and prevent the messages from showing in screen/terminal by using as follows:

```
my_script 2> "my_error_message_file"
```

SOLUTION TO GETTING BACK YOUR ERROR MESSAGES AFTER SCRIPT FINISHED

I think to open your error message file you will have to put some codes at the end of your script to open the error message file

> cat "my_error_message_file"

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. I have no problem hiding the error message from screen, what my problem is is to show the error afterwards

Comment: i edited my comment for a little solution I would have done..however i don't know any other way of doing this..best of luck..